# I'd like to divide the strings to two array

Tags: c#

I have a string data like `"aaa.bbb.ccc"` or `"aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"`.
If I split this like `"aaa.bbb.ccc".split(".")`, it becomes `"aaa"`, `"bbb"` and `"ccc"`.
I want to divide this to just two strings like `"aaa"`, `"bbb.ccc"`.
I think I can do this by firstly dividing everything and rejoining it but it's not smart way.
Is there any way to set this more smoothly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the number of splitted parts:

```
string myString = "aaa.bbb.ccc";
int parts = 2;
string[] myParts = myString.Split(new string[] {"."}, parts, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split on the first dot character, use `Substring`:

```
String value = "aaa.bbb.ccc";
Int32 firstDotIdx = value.IndexOf( '.' );
if( firstDotIdx > -1 ) {
    return new String[] {
        value.Substring( 0, firstDotIdx ),
        value.Substring( firstDotIdx + 1 );
    }
} else {
    return new String[] {
        value,
        "";
    }
}
```

- If you have "`aaa.bbb`" then it will return `{ "aaa", "bbb" }`.
- If you have "`aaa.bbb.ccc`" then it will return `{ "aaa", "bbb.ccc" }`.
- If you have "`.aaa.bbb`" then it will return `{ "", "aaa.bbb" }`.
- If you have "`aaa`" then it will return `{ "aaa", "" }`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bunch of extension methods for these kind of string manipulations. An example usage for your task would look like this.

```
var str = "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd";
var result = new[] { str.TakeUntil("."), str.TakeFrom(".") };
```

And the extension pack looks like this. The functions` results will not include the search string itself, and if the search string is not present in the input, they will return the whole input as result (this is a convention which suites my needs for this edge case, could be changed).

```
public static string TakeUntil(this string s, string search)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
    var pos = s.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (pos >= 0)
        return s.Substring(0, pos);
    return s;
}
public static string TakeUntilLast(this string s, string search)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
    var pos = s.LastIndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (pos >= 0)
        return s.Substring(0, pos);
    return s;
}

public static string TakeFrom(this string s, string search)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
    var pos = s.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (pos >= 0)
        return s.Substring(pos + search.Length);
    return s;
}
public static string TakeFromLast(this string s, string search)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
    var pos = s.LastIndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (pos >= 0)
        return s.Substring(pos + search.Length);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. I need to learn about the code provided. It seems to be very useful for me.